# Android SIP send location

Tags: android, geolocation, location, sip

I'm developing an app with the SDK API SIP. Ive got all the call stablishment ok, but my real problem is that i want to show the location of the user that is calling me during the proccess of call.

I've been reading about PARCEL cause SIP API have 2 functions of it, but i dont think thats the way. I just want to send the coordinates to put them in the API that Google offers me to show the map.

Does anybody can tell me an idea of how to send those values from the caller to the receiver??

Could be a solution, put those values as extra values in the PendingIntent that u create for the open function? If i the caller put them in, the receiver will receive them?

Thanks!!!

Yep, I'm noob in android. It's my first app XD